# Username setup in TortoiseHG

Tags: configuration, mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm trying to set up a local repository with TortoiseHG.  It's not linked to any remote repository; I just want to be able to manage changes on my own box.

Creating the repository went fine, but when I go to commit, I get an error:

> **Commit: Invalid username**
>
> Your username has not been configured.
>
> Please configure your username and try again.

It very helpfully pops up a username configuration dialog.  I fill in my username, and the rest of the options on that page just in case, and close it, try again... same error.  I've given it a username, and it remembers it, but it still won't commit.

What am I missing?

Comment: After setting the username close the commit dialogue and try to commit again. That fixed it for me.

Comment: @Milen: ...of course. Yeah, that worked. Submit it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Milen: Thanks - you just saved my day! You should post it as an answer, so it can be marked green and more visible =)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After setting the username, make sure you close the commit dialogue rather than simply trying again from the open form.  Then try to commit again. That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find the hgrc file in my Windows 7 drive, so I just added the username to the mercurial.ini file.

```
[ui]  
username = Santiago Villafuerte
```

The file is found in:

```
C:\Users\<your_windows_username>
```

I am using the x64 Tortoise release.

Answer (score 1):

To make it permanent, you should set it up in your `hgrc` file, in `[ui]` section, for example:

```
[ui]  
username = John Doe
```

See http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#files to get your `hgrc` location (probably in your home dir as `Mercurial.ini`).